# Perl Search and replace in 400'000 files

Tags: regex, perl

I've got about 400'000 files that need some text to be replaced.

I tried the following Perl script:

```
@files = <*.html>;

foreach $file (@files) {
    `perl -0777 -i -pe 's{<div[^>]+?id="user-info"[^>]*>.*?</div>}{}gsmi;' $file`;

    `perl -0777 -i -pe 's{<div[^>]+?class="generic"[^>]*>[^\s]*<small>[^\s]*Author.*?</div>.*?</div>.*?</div>.*?</div>.*?</div>}{}gsmi;' $file`;

    `perl -0777 -i -pe 's{<script[^>]+?src="javascript.*?"[^>]*>.*?</script>}{}gsmi;' $file`;

    `perl -p -i -e 's/.css.html/.css/g;' $file`;
}
```

I don't have a deep Perl knowledge, but the script runs too slow (updates only about 180 files per day).

Is there a way to speed it up?

Thank you in advance!

**PS:** When I tested it on a smaller number of files, I've noticed a much better performance...

Comment: Don't use backticks. Its very slow. Why not just open the files, do the changes and print it back?

Comment: Do you really have 400,000 files in a single directory, with no subdirectories? That's likely to cause problems, no matter how you access them; just opening a single file requires searching the directory. Can you set up a hierarchy of subdirectories?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately all of them are in one directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, if you load 400,000 file names into memory, that's going to suck up some memory. You can easily just iterate through the file list by for example:

- `File::Find`
- `opendir` + `while (readdir($dh))`  (does not load the entire list)

Second, using backticks spawns a new process in the shell, and it is very ineffective. You could just open the files normally, slurp them, and then reprint to the same file name. E.g.

```
while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
    local $/;
    my $text = <$fh>;                # slurp file
    $text =~ s/....//g;              # do your substitutions
    open $fh, ">", $file or die $!;
    print $fh $text;                 # overwrite file, same as -i switch does
}
```

Lastly.. using regexes to edit html is not ideal. It might work for your case, but it might be worthwhile to invest some time learning an html parser. Not sure how suitable it would be for this particular case, but it might be worth looking into, to make your code more stable.

Comment: Thank you! But will opening each file, then writing it back be faster than just applying a regex to it?

Comment: @user1751343 Spawning a new process to apply the regex will be a lot slower, yes. This is what perl was built to do, and does it quite fast. If you doubt me, you can always check out the Benchmark module and test it.

Comment: Just tried it, and it seems to work incredibly fast! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1751343 You're welcome. Yes, perl is optimized for these kinds of things. Backticks are slow and cumbersome in comparison. It would be interesting to hear how fast it completes, compared to the old speed of 180 per day. :)

Comment: It took about 6 hours for the script to update all the files :)

Answer (score 8):

Calling perl from perl will always be slower than doing all the work in one process. So, the solution might be

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN { undef $/ }
             s{<div[^>]+?id="user-info"[^>]*>.*?</div>}{}gsmi;
             s{<div[^>]+?class="generic"[^>]*>[^\s]*<small>[^\s]*Author.*?</div>.*?</div>.*?</div>.*?</div>.*?</div>}{}gsmi;
             s{<script[^>]+?src="javascript.*?"[^>]*>.*?</script>}{}gsmi;
             s/.css.html/.css/g;
    ' *.html
```

Comment: Shouldn't this populate `@ARGV` with 400.000 strings? Do normal shells even support that?

Comment: @amon: You can iterate over the files in Perl. What I was trying to show was how not to call perl from perl.